# Some classes such as rotate and scale (the known two) stopped working after upgrading from TailwindCSS 2 to 3

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, tailwind-in-js, tailwind-3

I was trying to use the newly introduced `arbitrary value` in TailwindCSS yesterday and it occured to me that I needed to upgrade from version 2 to the latest version. I religiously followed the upgrade guide and everything seemed working until I realized the `scale` and `rotate` in my site have stopped working. I battled it over the night with no luck.

I have another NextJS project that originally uses TailwindCSS version 3, I tried `scale` and `rotate` on it and it worked fine. The version is a bit lower (3.X.4) compared to the current version (3.X.23), so I downgraded to that exact version, yet the scaling and rotating wouldn't work.

I'm currently frustrated as I don't know what I didn't do or what I did wrongly. Can someone please rescue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haha!!! I figured it!

Actually, I was using custom classes instead of individual utility classes which means I don't necessarily need the import the `@tailwind base` into my globals.css.

I realized that whenever I import the `@tailwind base`, the `scale` and `rotate` start working, but some of my other stylings are disorganized (because the base styles over-write my styles). So, to make it work I read here https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight that one can disable the preset from the `tailwind.config.js` file by adding

```
corePlugins: {
preflight: false,
```

},

Comment: As a note, this seems to be covered in the [upgrade notes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrade-guide#base-layer-must-be-present), though I missed it too.